# Modify the loop in the right way

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, include

i got this graphic of a graph below. Now, the every node has a unique id number. My goal is to seperate out and return only the links between the red nodes, beginning from the left one and end at the right one. So the combination of node id's would be: `1-3-9-2`. My problem is that i got an `Array` which returns: `1-3-9-2-5-6-7`. That means also with the white nodes. Unfortunally i have to use that array. Each link between the nodes has a source and a target property. Target means that the arrow is pointing on the node and source means, the arrow is pointing away.

Now here is my problem: When i use the code below

```
function (d){
if( Array.includes(d.target) && Array.includes(d.source) {
   highlight the links
}
```

it highlights all links, because the white nodes are also a part of `Array`.
So how can i highlight the connection between 1 and 3, but not between 1 and 5 for example? All based on the the data of `Array`? I could use a loop for the first 4 elements and stop at the 5th. My plan is to say: only a connection between one element and the one which comes after that. That means only between the first and the second, the second and the third, the third and the fourth and so on. How can i do that?
Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: Are the red nodes 'targets', and the white nodes 'source', or is the other way around, or some other order?

Comment: It is mostly mixed.

Comment: I understand the 'mix' of the two in the array, but does red imply a target and the source not red?

Comment: Oh, no. Now i understand. I just edited the picture.

Comment: The red ones are only the first four elements of the Array and the combination i am looking for.

Comment: Right, so are those 'targets', and the others at the end of the array 'source'?  Where I'm going with my thought: if d.target is found in the array, which would be one of the first 4 based on the example, then make those red and don't do anything (or do something different) if d.source is found in the array. Does this make sense? (not that I'm right, just my perception at the moment)

Comment: No :) target only means that the arrow is pointing on the node and source means, the arrow is pointing away.

Comment: Then I might need an example, so for #3, what would be the relation of the three arrows (between 1 and 3, 3 and 9, 3 and 6, as far as target and source?

Comment: These arrows have no meaning. I just draw them because i highlight with the use of the source and target property. But when i am able to find out how to write a if-statement that check if there is a connection between 1 and 3, 3 and 9, 9 and 2, then these source and target properties are not needed. I am looking for a loop that makes a connection between Array[0] and Array[1], Array[1] and Array[2]. Array[2] and Array[3] and so on

Comment: Ok, I may still be missing something, but I'm not clear how you can separate the two when target and source are in the same array?  Is there other properties in the 'd' object that could help here?